# Scala regex for string extraction between . and whitespace

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following string:

```
val str = "tagged.big AND tagged.medium"
```

I need to implement regex that will find all assurance of `tagged.` till the first whitespace or the end of the line. In the current `str` I expect to extract 2 strings:

```
tagged.big
tagged.medium
```

This is my current attempt:

```
val pattern = "tagged.*\\s".r
```

but it returns:

```
Some(tagged.big AND )
```

Could you please show the proper regexp for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `tagged\.\S+` should work here.  This would match `tagged.` followed by one or more whitespace characters.  Here is a demo:

### Demo

This is how I would write the pattern.  The problem with your current pattern is that the `.*` is greedy, and will keep consuming as much as possible before hitting a whitespace character.  Also, in the case of the final match, `tagged.medium`, there is no whitespace character which occurs after it.  So, we could try using this:

```
tagged.*?(?=\s|$)
```

This [also works](https://regex101.com/r/Sn25Ld/2).